# MySQL: Inserting longtext > 20Mb

Tags: mysql, insert, blob, longtext

I have a file which the contents need to be inserted into a database longtext column.

```
INSERT into mail_queue(body) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('/tmp/.txtt3ucEx'))
```

What I get in return is

```
#1048 - Column 'body' cannot be null
```

Yes, I have increased my `max_packet_size` to more than cater for this.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the filename starting with a . makes MySQL not read the file properly.

Fixed it by making filename /tmp/t3ucEx.txt which is what i was trying to do in the first place!